# Feature layer from arcmap to arcGIS for server?

Tags: javascript, gis, arcmap

I am just wondering how I can go about publishing a feature layer in arcmap, and save that as a service to arcGIS for server, so I can call the service in my code in order to generate the feature layer for a web map?

So far I can only find resources in regards to publishing a feature layer to ArcGIS online. I am wanting to publish the feature layer from arcmap to arcGIS for server and call from javascript API to generate a web map.

Comment: You can look into posting this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com where these kinds of questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways I use to do this.  I first log into my server with the ArcGIS Server installation.  Open up ArcMap on that system.  It is basically the same thing as a regular ArcMap but has a couple more tools you will be using. Mainly, you will be using the Map Service Publishing toolbar.  It contains tools that allow you to analyze, preview, and publish your map.

Set up your map document to show the layer in the manner you want it to appear when you're showing it in a web application.  You can set symbology, scale dependencies, labeling, etc...

Once that is set, you need to publish it as a service.  I work off 9.3.1 but 10.x should be pretty similar.  I believe in the 10.x installations, you must analyze your map before it allows you to publish.  It is a good idea to analyze it anyway because it gives you suggestions to get the app running faster.

You have two options when publishing a map to the ArcGIS Server.  You can publish the map document as a service or save a map service definition file.  I typically do the map service definition files because it is supposed to render faster (according to ESRI).

This ESRI link gives better, more precise information too: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003vt000000

Best thing to do when you're first starting out playing with this is to go to videos.arcgis.com and search through the developers presentations from ESRI's Developer Conferences.  They are typically hour long segments that have presenters going through and describing how to do all sorts of things with ESRI software.

I am assuming you're using ESRI's JavaScript API to consume the map service.  When you publish a service, you get the option to share it as a WMS service too.  That would be more useful if you were using open source tools like OpenLayers to consume the map service.

This is a bit of an introduction into doing this.  The major problems you may have is getting administrative privileges on your server and making sure the user accounts are set up properly.  My biggest hiccups came from not having permission to administer the server.